# Passing Arrays through Functions Using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So my program is supposed to calculate the area of an slant cylinder with an irregular pentagonal cross. I've managed to do it before with a lot more code by passing values down individually using loops but I want to shorten my program and make it more efficient. From what I understand I can pass the address of a variable to a function and store it in a pointer, I can then set the value of that pointer to the first value in the array and access it by calling on the variable in the main function. I then understand that by using something like *(p+1) I can access the next value in the array. However I can't seem to figure out how this works. Here is my code. My program works by reading a set of 5 coordinates, calculating the length of the lines, finding the areas of the triangles they form, summing them and multiplying by the height of the shape. Any help is apreciated.
Just by the way: The program runs, the value of *p and line[0] are the same however the rest are not.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SIZE 5
int
main(void)
{
    FILE *in = fopen("pfile1", "r");
    int x[SIZE], y[SIZE], i;
    double h, polygon;
    printf("x Values   y Values\n");
    if (NULL != in){
        for (i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
            fscanf(in, "%d %d", &x[i], &y[i]);
        for (i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
            printf("%4d %10d\n", x[i], y[i]);
        fscanf(in, "%lf", &h);
        printf("height = %lf\n", h);
    }
    fclose(in);
    polygon = poly_area(x, y, h);
    printf("The area of the polygon is: %.4lf meters squared", polygon);
    return(0);
}
void
tri_side(int xArr[SIZE] , int yArr[SIZE], double *n)
{
    double line[7];
    line[0] = sqrt(pow((xArr[1] - xArr[0]),2) + pow((yArr[1] - yArr[0]),2));
    line[1] = sqrt(pow((xArr[2] - xArr[1]),2) + pow((yArr[2] - yArr[1]),2));
    line[2] = sqrt(pow((xArr[3] - xArr[2]),2) + pow((yArr[3] - yArr[2]),2));
    line[3] = sqrt(pow((xArr[4] - xArr[3]),2) + pow((yArr[4] - yArr[3]),2));
    line[4] = sqrt(pow((xArr[4] - xArr[0]),2) + pow((yArr[4] - yArr[0]),2));
    line[5] = sqrt(pow((xArr[4] - xArr[1]),2) + pow((yArr[4] - yArr[1]),2));
    line[6] = sqrt(pow((xArr[4] - xArr[2]),2) + pow((yArr[4] - yArr[2]),2));
    *n = line[0];
}
void
tri_area(int xArr[SIZE], int yArr[SIZE], double *n)
{
    double triArea1, triArea2, triArea3, s, a, b, c;
    double *p, sides, triArea[3];
    tri_side(xArr, yArr, &sides);
    p = &sides;
    a = *p;
    b = *(p+1);
    c = *(p+5);
    s = (a + b + c)/2;
    triArea1 = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
    triArea[0] = triArea1;
    a = *(p+1);
    b = *(p+5);
    c = *(p+6);
    s = (a + b + c)/2;
    triArea2 = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
    triArea[1] = triArea2;
    a = *(p+2);
    b = *(p+3);
    c = *(p+6);
    s = (a + b + c)/2;
    triArea3 = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
    triArea[2] = triArea3;
    *n = triArea[0];
}
double
pent_area(int xArr[SIZE], int yArr[SIZE])
{
    int i;
    double pentArea, area1, area2, area3, areas, *p;
    tri_area(xArr, yArr, &areas);
    p= &areas;
    pentArea = *(p) + *(p+1) + *(p+2);
    printf("Pentagon Area :%lf\n", pentArea);
    return(pentArea);
}
int
poly_area(int xArr[SIZE], int yArr[SIZE], double h)
{
    double pentArea, polyArea;
    pentArea = pent_area(xArr, yArr);
    polyArea = h * pentArea;
    return(polyArea);
}
```

Comment: Here you are passing an empty pointer (dereference, in this case) to a function call... why?
`double *p, sides, triArea[3];
    tri_side(xArr, yArr, &sides);
    p = &sides;`

Comment: You probably mean to return *n from tri_side, right?

Comment: As you've said you're very new to programming, I would highly, HIGHLY recommend reading about scopes and pointers, check out C in a Nutshell, probably the best book ever written for C programmers. However, pick your resource of choice. It seems you haven't learned how to return values from functions yet, which is a pretty early step in C programming. It feels like you're a bit beyond your level at this point. Definitely read about pointers, at the very least.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass back a pointer to stack allocated memory ie

```
double *p, sides, triArea[3];
```

you then try and pass this back by assigning it as follows

```
*n = triArea[0];
```

This means that in this code

```
double pentArea, area1, area2, area3, areas, *p;
tri_area(xArr, yArr, &areas);
p= &areas;
pentArea = *(p) + *(p+1) + *(p+2);
```

`p + 1` is not valid. When a function call returns the memory on the stack that it had used to create the local variables are no longer in scope ie you must not use them. If you want to use something from the function you need to pass it in and use it or allocate it on the heap in the function and pass it back.

Also. when passing pointers to arrays you can declare them as follows

```
pent_area(int xArr[], int yArr[])
```

I this case change this

```
tri_area(int xArr[SIZE], int yArr[SIZE], double *n)
```

to this

```
tri_area(int xArr[], int yArr[], double triAreas[])
```

Comment: So how exactly would I do that? Or fix this in my case.

Comment: The easiest way is to declare the array in the function and pass it as a param.

Comment: Sorry I'm still very new to programming, how would I do that in my program?

Comment: Would I do the same for my tri_side function? Or is that all I have to do?

Comment: Think about this line `double line[7];` in tri_side, the memory here has been declared on the stack ie when the function returns it's gone, kaput, nada, any attempt to use the pointer ie `line` in the calling function will result in Undefined Behavior. This line `*n = line[0];` is actually assigning a double value to `*n` not the pointer and even if you use `*n = line;` this still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I figured it out.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #define SIZE 5
    int
    main(void)
    {
        FILE *in = fopen("pfile1", "r");
        int x[SIZE], y[SIZE], i;
        double h, polygon;
        printf("x Values   y Values\n");
        if (NULL != in){
            for (i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
                fscanf(in, "%d %d", &x[i], &y[i]);
            for (i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
                printf("%4d %10d\n", x[i], y[i]);
            fscanf(in, "%lf", &h);
            printf("height = %lf\n", h);
        }
        fclose(in);
        polygon = poly_area(x, y, h);
        printf("The area of the polygon is: %.4lf meters squared", polygon);
        return(0);
    }
    void
    tri_side(int xArr[] , int yArr[], double line[7])
    {
        line[0] = sqrt(pow((xArr[1] - xArr[0]),2) + pow((yArr[1] - yArr[0]),2));
        line[1] = sqrt(pow((xArr[2] - xArr[1]),2) + pow((yArr[2] - yArr[1]),2));
        line[2] = sqrt(pow((xArr[3] - xArr[2]),2) + pow((yArr[3] - yArr[2]),2));
        line[3] = sqrt(pow((xArr[4] - xArr[3]),2) + pow((yArr[4] - yArr[3]),2));
        line[4] = sqrt(pow((xArr[4] - xArr[0]),2) + pow((yArr[4] - yArr[0]),2));
        line[5] = sqrt(pow((xArr[4] - xArr[1]),2) + pow((yArr[4] - yArr[1]),2));
        line[6] = sqrt(pow((xArr[4] - xArr[2]),2) + pow((yArr[4] - yArr[2]),2));
    }
    void
    tri_area(int xArr[], int yArr[], double triArea[3])
    {
        double s, a, b, c, triSides[7];
        tri_side(xArr, yArr, triSides);
        a = triSides[0];
        b = triSides[1];
        c = triSides[5];
        s = (a + b + c)/2;
        triArea[0]= sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
        a = triSides[1];
        b = triSides[5];
        c = triSides[6];
        s = (a + b + c)/2;
        triArea[1] = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)); 
        a = triSides[2];
        b = triSides[3];
        c = triSides[6];
        s = (a + b + c)/2;
        triArea[2] = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
    }
    double
    pent_area(int xArr[], int yArr[])
    {
        int i;
        double pentArea, areas[3];
        tri_area(xArr, yArr, areas);
        pentArea = areas[0]+areas[1]+areas[2];
        printf("Pentagon Area :%lf\n", pentArea);
        return(pentArea);
    }
    int
    poly_area(int xArr[], int yArr[], double h)
    {
        double pentArea, polyArea;
        pentArea = pent_area(xArr, yArr);
        polyArea = h * pentArea;
        return(polyArea);
    }
```